# ClearRenderTarget issues with some graphics cards

Tags: wpf, directx, sharpdx

I have a strange issue when rendering via SharpDX using certain graphics cards in a WPF environment using D3DImage.

I am using DirectX11, which is bound to the D3Dimage via a D3D9 texture using code from here: http://directx4wpf.codeplex.com/, although I have also managed to reproduce the problem by simply running the WPFHost example in the SharpDX samples.

The problem is that calls to ClearRenderTargetView do not seem to affect pixel blocks in the view port that are not also affected by a draw call. In the image below, I am rendering the gray polygon after a call to ClearRenderTargetView with a red colour. The image on the left is after a single render, the image on the right is after zooming out somewhat - note that the view has not cleared. If I simply make the clear call with no draw calls at all, I see nothing.

This issue only occurs when running on a laptop with Intel HD4000 integrated graphics (W7 64 bit). I don't get the issue on the same laptop when running through the dedicated GT 650M, or on my development desktop machine (W8, GTX645).

If I run the same code using DX11 directly in a Windows Forms host using the HD4000, I don't get the issue.

Use of DirectX and SharpDX is new to me, and I am trying to retro-fit some graphical improvements to an existing WPF app. So far it looks like deployment is going to be a headache..

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing this, and what fixes or workarounds are available? One thing I have thought of (but not tried) is to create a drawable object that completely fills the screen (e.g. transparent quad), as this would require every pixel block to be "touched". Doesn't seem like a very nice idea though.

thanks,
Matt

Comment: Is `ClearRenderTargetView` the only thing not working?  Also, do the unpainted areas flicker frame to frame or is the image stable?

Comment: It seems to be, in my limited example. What I am actually doing is clearing to transparent and rendering textured quads that build up the grey shape, and this part all seems to work fine. It seems to be just the clear that is failing, and as I mentioned in the question, if I simply clear to a fixed colour and do nothing else then this also fails.

Comment: Just a quick thought: I'm wondering about the aliasing, it looks like the clear and the drawing happens on different resolutions. Are you working with texture rendertargets or something which could have various resolutions?

Comment: NO - MSAA is disabled (quality (1,0)), and the clear call immediately precedes the draw indexed call, to the same context (ImmediateContext). It looks to me as if pixels are processed chunks - and any chunk that is touched by the draw call then goes on to also contain the result of the clear, but otherwise is not affected. Seems like a driver issue, insofar as I have only seen this effect on one machine so far (with integrated HD4000 GPU). Having said that, the failure rate is 33% across the machines I have tested on, and no doubt this issue would arise in the field..